# How can I log into Facebook without user intervention?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, cron, oauth-2.0, cron-task

**What I have**

I have an app which able to get `access_token`s of 2 hours and then 60 days.

**What I need**

I need to be able to run a cron job once once a month using my Facebook ID and password and tha run a ".php" file from my web server. I am able to set cron jobs but i don't know how to login to facebook automatically (i.e. without user intervention).

Is there any way to do this, like sending a request to: `http://facebook.com?user=ABDULLAH&pass=my_pass`?

Comment: @Jimmy Sawczuk 
first i say just thanks :)
than after reading text again i have to say it was actually perfeect 
thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

You're not going to be able to "log in" to Facebook in the way you describe, by sending a username and password.

What you can do is use an access token, either yours or your users', to make whatever API request you need. I'd recommend just storing the most recent access token for every user you have so you can get to it whenever you need to. When users comes back to your app, you'll need to refresh this access token so it won't expire on you.

When it comes time to use them, simply set the access token using the PHP SDK or by appending `&access_token=...` to the end of all your graph requests.

Comment: hi jimmy thanks for your answer but i try to do => i don't use facebook for many months but my app post a daily wall post or something similar its done with my 60 days access_token but after 60 days i have to use my app so that its get a new 60 days token but i want this process is also automatic means i don't want to use after 60 days i want thats its also done automatically like something that login to facebook with user intervention

Comment: Currently there's no way to renew an access token without user intervention. You'll need your users (or you) to log in periodically to refresh the access token.

Comment: `offline_access` is being deprecated and it looks like an API endpoint is added to allow a token's life to be extended by 60 days at a time; see https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/

Comment: @JimmySawczuk are you sure there is no other way 
i am thinking about something like auto form filling and submitting

Comment: @RichardBarnett i known and i already use 60 days access_token but i want this process completely automatic means no user interaction required after 50 or 6o to get new 60 days access_token hopes now you get my point

Comment: @AbdullahAdam no way that would be within terms. The accepted method is the one I outlined.

Comment: From the link I posted:  _The user must access your application before you're able to get a valid "authorization code" to be able to make the server-side OAuth call again. Apps will not be able to setup a background/cron job that tries to automatically extend the expiration time, because the "authorization code" is short-lived and will have expired._.  (I'm not sure if this _authorization code_ is ever visible to the app.)  So FB explicitly say you can't do what you want to do.  I agree with @JimmySawczuk that you can't do this without violating the terms of use.

Comment: You can renew your accessToken after 60 days without user intervation using this URL: `"/oauth/access_token?  
    grant_type=fb_exchange_token&           
    client_id={app-id}&
    client_secret={app-secret}&
    fb_exchange_token={short-lived-token}"` -> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#extending